# Read from VisualFoxPro .DBF remote location

Tags: asp.net, .net, connection, dbf, visual-foxpro

I have problem with connecting to DBF files on remote location using OleDb.
When I use local path everything works fine.

My connection string:

```
string path_dbf = @"\\server\directory";
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source="+path_dbf+";");
```

I've tried to use OleDb and Odbc, but both have failed when I use remote location. I also try to use mapped directory under the OS, but it doesn't work.

I get error:

> Error: Sys.Net.WebServiceFailedException: The server method 'MethodName' failed with the following error: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException-- Invalid path or file name.

I also try to use Odbc DSN like this:

```
OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection("dsn=MyDsnName;");
```

but it doesn't work. MyDsnName is Free Table directory type and it points to my mapped remote directory.

I don't have idea of any possible solution.
So I want to ask if there is a maybe some additional connection string options to do that or I do something wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably a permissions issue when running as a web app.  The user which may be something like "USR_MACHINE" may not have proper permissions to the other server location and thus failing.

To confirm this, try changing your website service to "Run As" some other user that DOES have permissions, such as yourself... if STILL not a problem, then try running .net as the ADMINISTRATOR FOR CONFIRMATION PURPOSES ONLY, then revert back to the USR_MACHINE account.

Once you have confirmed, then you might want to create a somewhat restricted user so they only have access to the folder and features you want them to for security purposes.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Your answer help me a lot. I set ApplicationPool Identity to user that have permission to remote directory and it works fine.